# How can I localize a simple website without using any frameworks?

Tags: javascript, html, localization, web

Salut everyone.

I have a very lightweight website containing some js and some html. I want to add such functionality: a user can press one button, and the website changes its language.

This website contains at most 100 strings, so I don't want to use any frameworks or libraries.

What is the best practice to do such things? Can you give any code examples if you please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you specifically said no frameworks or libraries, a bare-bones way is simply to build an object containing your translations, then update the DOM after the user selects the language.

Your HTML might look liks this:

```
<span data-l10n="hello">hello</span>
```

and your script like this (assuming you have a <select> element for choosing the language):

```
var l10n = {
    "en" : {
        "hello" : "hello"
    },
    "fr" : {
        "hello" : "bonjour"
    }
};

document.getElementById('#language-selector').onchange = function() {
    var language = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,
        nodes = document.querySelectorAll('[data-l10n]'),
        i = nodes.length,
        key;
    while (i--) {
        var key = nodes[i].getAttribute('data-l10n');
        nodes[i].innerHTML = l10n[language][key];
    }
};
```

Untested but you should be able to get the idea. Like I say, this is about as basic as you can get so probably not best practise (since Google will only index the default language, etc).

Comment: Thank you, I guess, it's what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use some small independent localisation library instead reinventing the wheel, which will definitely save you a lot of time and headaches.

For example [webL10n](https://github.com/fabi1cazenave/webL10n), simple, well documented, IE6+ compatibility

Comment: Thanks, I will definetly check this out.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the easy steps below to add the google translate widget to your website.

**Step 1:**
Go to https://translate.google.com/manager/website/ and sign in to your Google account when you are prompted to.

**Step 2:**
Click on the "Add to your website now" button on the right-hand side.

**Step 3:**
On the next page, you will be required to complete two parts:

1. Enter the URL of your website into the empty "Website URL" field
   (for example: www.yourwebsite.com).
2. Choose the original language of your website from the dropdown menu.

Click the Next button.

**Step 4**
On this page you will choose whether you want to be able to translate into all of the available languages, or only the languages that you choose. You will also choose how the translate widget will look on your website, and advanced features.

When you're done making these choices, click Get Code.

**Step 5**
On the next page you will see two codes that you need to insert onto your website.

The first code is a meta tag. To add this to your JimdoPage, copy the code and go to Settings > Website > Edit Head and paste the whole code there. Make sure to hit Save!

The second code is your widget code. Choose where you want the translator dropdown to show up on your website (we suggest adding it to the Sidebar), add a Widget / HTML element to that part of your page, then paste the widget code into the new element.

**Step 6**
You can manage the translations made on your website, in case you want to ensure that they are done properly and edit them if the translations aren't quite correct. To do this, click on the Manage Translations button at the end of the embedding process.

You can reach this option any time by going to https://translate.google.com/manager/website/suggestions and logging in to your Google account.

Comment: Thanks, I will save this information for future use. Can be useful when site have a lot of languages and you don't have translator folks near you.

Comment: Your Welcome Steel !